# My son is traveling to Italy with his school will he need a green card and if so why

Tags: uk, italy, children

uk Liverpool to Italy why do I need a green card. 
Traveling by coach

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Sorry, it is not very clear what you are asking. Presumably by *green card* you mean the permesso di soggiorno, but why do you ask if your son needs one in one place and why you need one in another? Who is asking for it? How old is your son and what is the purpose of the trip, and how long will he be staying? By coach do you mean a long-distance motorcoach, or are you referring to a rail or air travel class?

Comment: Also, wouldn't the school send home instructions about any visas or permits the children will need?

Answer (score 4):

I presume you are asking because you have seen the green card listed as a document required for entry into Italy.  If so, that entry refers to the [international motor vehicle insurance card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Motor_Insurance_Card_System), and it is only required of people who are bringing a vehicle into Italy.

The other possibility is that it refers to a US permanent resident card, but that document is not generally required of people traveling to Italy.

All your son needs to enter Italy is a passport or EU national ID card.  If your son is not an EU citizen, he'll need his passport and possibly, depending on his nationality, a visa.